# JDBC and Oracle conn.commit and conn.setAutocommit not working properly

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, connection

I have made a DBManager class as shown below

```
public class DBManager {


      public static String DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
      public static String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/DB";
      public static String USERNAME = "afsweb";
      public static String PASSWORD = "afsweb";
      public static String DOCDBUSERNAME = "docdb";
      public static String DOCDBPASSWORD = "docdb";
      public static int PORT = 1521;

    //static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ExcelDBManager.class.getName());
    public static Connection getConnection(String url ,String username, String password){
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return con;
}
```

And i have method truncate rows in table

```
public static void truncate() throws SQLException{
        conn = DBManager.getConnection(DBManager.URL, DBManager.USERNAME, DBManager.PASSWORD);
        System.out.println(conn.getAutoCommit()  +"");
        Statement pstmnt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{    
            pstmnt = conn.createStatement();
            pstmnt.executeQuery("truncate table bd_vehicles_temp_1");
            System.out.println("Query Executed");
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
            if(rs !=null){
                rs.close();
            }
            if(pstmnt != null){
                pstmnt.close();
            }
            if(conn != null){
                conn.close();
            }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i have not written conn.commit inside my truncate() method. Also i have setAutocommit to false. Even then the changes are reflected in database.

On Executing the above method i get output as

```
false
Query Executed
```

Which means my connections autocommit mode is false. Still the changes made by truncate method is reflected in database. What could be the possible reason  ?? I am using Oracle Database.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` is a Data Definition Language (DDL) command which commits implicitly. It wouldn't have committed anything, had you used the `DELETE` statement instead.

```
// Deletes ALL Rows; No WHERE Clause
pstmnt.executeQuery("DELETE FROM bd_vehicles_temp_");
```

The reason `TRUNCATE` is a DDL statement is that it removes the table data directly without copying it into the *Rollback Tablespace*. That's why `TRUNCATE` is faster but cannot be rolled back.

***EDIT** : (Why my INSERTs are committing as well?)*

That's because you're closing your *Connection* without calling [Connection#rollback()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28%29).

If a *Connection* is closed without an explicit *commit* or a *rollback*; JDBC does not mandate anything in particular here and hence the behaviour is dependent on the database vendor. In case of Oracle, an implict *commit* is issued.

> It is **strongly recommended** that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined.

SO, just `rollback()` your changes before closing your *Connection* in the *finally* block

```
pstmnt = conn.createStatement();

pstmnt.executeQuery("DELETE FROM bd_vehicles_temp_1");
System.out.println("Query Executed");

conn.rollback();
System.out.println("Changes rolled back");
```

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I've added my response as an update to my answer. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 4):

`TRUNCATE TABLE` basically doesn't allow commit/rollback in the normal way. As per [this documentation](http://psoug.org/reference/truncate.html):

> Because a Truncate is DDL it issues a COMMIT before it acts and another COMMIT afterward so no rollback of the transaction is possible.

If you want to do this as part of a transaction, use DML instead - e.g. a normal `DELETE FROM ...` statement.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh: Insert? I thought you were trying to delete?

Comment: This is a different scenario where i face the same problem for inserting rows

Comment: @AbhishekSingh: Then I think it would be worth asking about it in a different question. Your question is solely about TRUNCATE TABLE, which has a very natural explanation - one which doesn't necessarily apply to INSERT.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle truncate command is DDL and it issues commit implicitly. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/truncate-table.html

Answer (score 2):

Autocommit behavior depends on the underlying database you use. An unfortunately in your case Oracle's JDBC driver commits on close() by default.

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason ? I get the same result even if i do insert !

Comment: @AbhishekSingh As far as i know, the autocommit flag will not change anything for oracle driver, as the connection is committed as soon as it is closed.

Comment: Any sources for that ? Because in that case i will have to do conn.rollback !

Comment: There used to be a wiki page for that, but it is removed now. I am searching for the source. But if you confirmed the behavior then you can plan accordingly.

Comment: Will go with conn.rollback ?